# Pulling page content to string android

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to pull a php page to string on android.
The problem is that I can't get the response_str variable outside of the try.
Whatever I'm doing it keep returning null.
The URL return 1 or 0.

this is my code:

```
public String IsLoggedIn() {
        String url_text = "http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php";
        String response_str = null;
        try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.toString());
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response_str;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
10-31 20:33:27.906: I/chromium(13374): [INFO:CONSOLE(74)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'n33_scrolly'", source: http://www.klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/js/init.js (74)
```

Thank you,
Morha13

Comment: Your error is on the server side. `isloggedin.php`has errors caused by a missing method `n33_scrolly` inside your `init.js`

Comment: @nem I don't understand why is it happening.. This page only return 0 or 1.. Do you have any idea what causes that?

Comment: there could be a gazzilion reasons and I don't have the time nor capabilities to externally debug a web page, look inside `isloggedin.php` and init.js`, maybe use the developers console in Chrome or Firefox and debug stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing that on the Main Thread then you might be getting NetworkOnMainThreadException.

If that is the case, try moving your code to a background thread like using AsyncTask.

And don't forget the INTERNET permission.

Try this:

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url_text = "http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php";
            String response_str = null;
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.toString());
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);

                Log.v("Response", response_str);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: What is happening at your side? Have you checked the log and don't see the response? Are you getting exception for example?

Comment: I really don't know, I have tons of problems with this part of the script and I tried tens of tutorials online and nothing worked. If you can help me, I'm trying to create a script that gets the boolean in this webpage: http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php and save it in to a string

Comment: @user3825694 I have executed the code I posted above and it is getting the value zero. You must debug the code and tell me what is happening so I can help you.

Comment: It's giving me an error even before exporting.. http://i.gyazo.com/1089640dbe8b0e4788e25abf2cf91a79.png

Comment: @user3825694 This code is not a method definition. It has to be put in a method. You need to spend more time learning programming basics before trying to do tasks like these.